# Moving Sprites are not being selected via nodeAtPoint Method

Tags: animation, sprite-kit, touchesbegan, skaction

So I have sprites, which are generated randomly in the screen and are then given random movements via SKAction.

For example:

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Icicle.png"];
sprite.position = CGPointMake (randomX, 0); //randomX is a random integer between 0 and screen width

SKAction *action = [SKAction moveToY:-200 duration:2];

[sprite runAction:action];

[self addChild:sprite];
```

Now in my touches began method:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

}
```

What I am seeing is that my nodes are not getting selected very accurately. The Icicle images have a buffer width of 20 pixels around all four sides.

Does being in the middle of an SKAction, make node selection via tapping inaccurate?

Moreover, any suggestions on how to select nodes that are constantly moving via a touchesbegan method?

Comment: Why you are saying that your nodes are not getting selected very accuratelly? Your code looks OK. How you testing it ? Have you tried checking it like this `NSLog(@"%@", node);` ?

Comment: I try animating the node once selected, and removing it from the scene. However this does not happen, and the game has a broken feel.

Comment: @user2068588 Those images have 20px fully transparent area around actual content ? Do you use atlases ?

Comment: Your descriptions are vague at best. You posted code is not that relevant with your last comment of "I try animating the node once selected, and removing it from the scene. However this does not happen...". Edit your question to say what you want, include all the relevant code and finally describe what is actually happening.

Comment: @ whirlwind No I am not using atlases. it is a png image with a 20 px wide transparent area around 4 sides of the graphic. This was done so when a user would tap near the sprite, it would select the sprite.

Comment: @sangony the animation code is not important. What is happening is that the when I tap, and the code is at the touchesbegan method, even when it looks as if I am tapping on the sprite on the device, the nodeatpoint method is not returning the node/sprite. It is returning null, most of the time, even though it seems I am tapping the image. I was wondering that since I have run an SKAction to the node, making it move to the bottom of the screen 

SKAction *action = [SKAction moveToY:-200 duration:2];

[sprite runAction:action];

[self addChild:sprite];

Does that make nodeAtPoint innacurate?

Comment: If the size of your sprite is too small, you could experience difficulties registering the touch. I suggest you just place the sprite on the screen, do not run a movement action and see if you can register a touch. When debugging you need to start at the beginning and work your way forward step by step to see where the issue is.